# PHP composer.json file autoload statement for 3rd party PHP classes in a subdirectory

Tags: composer-php, autoload

I am currently developing an PHP app using Silex framework and have the following directory structure:

```
public_html
|-- myapp
|   |-- classes (3rd party php files)
|   |-- manager (core php files)
|-- vendor (contains Silex related libs)
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
|-- index.php
```

And have the following composer.json content:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "Manager\\": ["myapp/"] }
    }
}
```

Adding "autoload" to the composer JSON file, I was able to load all the php files in

```
public_html/myapp/manager/*.php
```

Using "Manager" as PHP namespace.I would also like autoload 3rd party php files in

```
public_html/myapp/classes/*.php
```

But the 3rd party php files doesn't use namespace. How can I add to the autoload statement? I have tried adding several different statements the run composer update but didn't work at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, you can always add a classmap autoloader for that third party library.